# 06 Nissan Altima won’t fire after dead battery

Tags: starting, nissan

I came outside this morning and found that my car battery was dead. After an attempt to jumpstart I put it on the charger for several hours, but the car still won’t start. It has been running fine otherwise. The engine cranks over but does not fire. I can smell fuel if I pump the gas pedal a bit.    If I pump the pedal it tries to fire and runs very rough but will never catch and hold done.